# Using Java String.format

Tags: java, string.format

I have a string "name" which I need to add n amount of blank spaces to the end. I have been told to use String.format but for the life of me I cant figure out how to do it.

```
String formatName = String.format(name, %15s);
return formatName;
```

But this didn't work, can anyone point me in the right the direction?

Basically I need to make each string 15 characters long with blank spaces appended to the end if the original string is too short.

================

With advice I reversed the paramaters however this throws up an error.

```
private String format(String name, String number) 
{
    String formatName = String.format(%15s, name);
    String formatNumber = String.format(%15s, number);
    return formatName + " - " + formatNumber;
}
```

However this throws an error - Illegal start of expression.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You've got your parameters backwards. Look at the API for java.util.Formatter for more details.

Comment: `formatName = String.format("%-15s", name)`.

Comment: @aioobe nice, didn't know that one, but that does not add n spaces to the end, it pads it until the string is n characters. Chris, is this what was required or did you really require precisely n spaces?

Comment: @Chris, the format string needs to be between quotes like `"%-15s"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
formatName = String.format(name + "%15s", "");
```

OR

```
formatName = String.format("%-15s", name);
```

The `-` appends to the end of the argument.